# ORM one-to-many relationship with optional columns in foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do something that may be dumb, but let's try.

I am working with sqlalchemy and defining the following two tables:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    children = relationship("Child", cascade='all, delete-orphan')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

So far so good, I can have a parent with multiple children, when the parent is deleted the children conveniently do the same.

Now I want to take care of orphans. Those have no parent, but they live in an orphanage. I first build the orphanage:

```
class Orphanage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orphanage'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    children = relationship("Child", cascade='all, delete-orphan')
```

But now I need to be able to connect a child to an orphanage **instead** of a parent.
I'd like to replace the foreign key in the child to something like :

```
custodian_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id' or 'orphanage.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

Is there a relationship model that could support that?

Thank you!

Comment: At the database level you cannot have a column that is a FK to more than 1 table.You would need a second FK to Orphanage, both would need to be null-able and a check that exactly one is null in each row. Alternatively, make Orphanage a sub-type of Parent, Keep the Child table the same, and relate Parent to Orphanage (still a new table). The Parent-Child remains the same and additional processes for Orphanage-Parent-Child are available (just in case the government gets involved).  Maybe not the best solution but workable.

Comment: Thank you @Belayer, can you please explain a bit about "relate Parent to Orphanage"? Do you mean that there will be some sort of a dummy parent between the orphanage and the child that'll cascade the operations?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you create a 'dummy' parent, but it does not sit between parent and child. You create a table for Orphanages but that becomes another child table for Parent (Or that could be reversed). It is more difficult to explain than show. So I'll show how. (Disclaimer: I do not know SQLAlchemy so the format may quite correct, but you should get the idea).  
First off, creating a Orphanages table assumes there are additional attributes and you have simplified for the question. If that is not the case then perhaps just adding a boolean to Parent may be sufficient.

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    is_orphanage = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    children = relationship("Child", cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
```

That would identify Orphans and the Orphanage, without additional changes. However assuming there will be sufficient other processing for Orphanages the following is *one way* to approach it:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    children = relationship("Orphanage")
    children = relationship("Child", cascade='all, delete-orphan'))

class Orphanage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orphanage'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))

 class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

An example may be in order but I'll have to do that from the database side. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=eaaf093a16b24899f1336a20acf6cf7b) here.  
This presents just 1 of several possibilities. The overall idea is to preserve the ability to handle Parent-Child processing the same whether child is an orphan or not while adding the capability to process separately when required. And do so with minimal data structure changes.  
I guess I would be remiss not mentioning [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html). So follow the link. Perhaps Orphanage can inherit from parent (at least with the current attributes). But I tend to avoid it as I don't like the Postgres implementation. It may, however, work with your ORM.   Hope this is helpful.